# Match all cases between string and comma using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a large string. Here is a part of it:

```
{"status":"ok","items":[{"image_versions":[{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage8.instagram.com\/11a67042c62311e1bf341231380f8a12_7.jpg","width":612,"type":7,"height":612},{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage8.instagram.com\/11a67042c62311e1bf341231380f8a12_6.jpg","width":306,"type":6,"height":306},{"url":"http:\/\/distilleryimage8.instagram.com\/11a67042c62311e1bf341231380f8a12_5.jpg","width":150,"type":5,"height":150}],"code":"MrMBxJo-O8","has_more_comments":true,"taken_at":1341438972.0,"comments":[{"media_id":228329104165036988,"_spam":false,"text":"I live in Oklahoma! :D Shoot them off with me! :D","created_at":1341441914.0,"user":{"username":"heather_all_over","pk":13296276,"profile_pic_url":"http:\/\/images.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_13296276_75sq_1339538236.jpg","full_name":"Heather\ud83c\udf80","is_private":false},"content_type":"comment","pk":228353791620276525,"type":0},{"media_id":228329104165036988,"_spam":false,"text":"Wish I had that much money to spend.......","created_at":1341441916.0,"user":{"username":"l_mcnair","pk":23775741,"profile_pic_url":"http:\/\/images.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_23775741_75sq_1339894045.jpg","full_name":"Lauryn","is_private":true},"content_type":"comment","pk":228353803204944174,"type":0},{"media_id":228329104165036988,"_spam":false,"text":"You should video tape you setting them all off","created_at":1341441939.0,"user":{"username":"ahrii_","pk":37732021,"profile_pic_url":"http:\/\/images.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_37732021_75sq_1340907381.jpg","full_name":"Ahriana;-*","is_private":false},"content_type":"comment","pk":228353997065675057,"type":0},{"media_id":228329104165036988,"_spam":false,"text":"When did skrillex start selling
```

I am trying to match every number after "pk":". I have been trying look aheads but can't quite seem to get it right. I don't know much about regex so if somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the part **after** something you should use look-behind:

```
(?<="pk":)\d+
```

Comment: Have you tested this?  How do you know lookbehind is an option?  Not all flavors support it, and the OP hasn't said which flavor he's using.

Comment: yeah, he should have better mentioned!

Comment: But even if lookbehind is available, this regex won't work.  You left out the quotes around the `pk`, and the `.*` will consume the rest of the string, not just the numbers immediately following the `:`.

Comment: I am coding in C#/.Net. To the others asking why I wouldn't just parse the JSON, I figured that is a much more bulkier way to handle things as opposed to a quick and dirty regex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a JSON response. Why not just parse the JSON and pull out the values for all the "pk" keys?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what language you're using, the regex might look different, but this should work on most languages:

```
/"pk":(\d+)/g
```

That basically looks for the string "pk": and then all the digits after that, placing those digits in a capturing group.  The g at the end makes it search for all occurrences.  Depending on the language you're using though, you might not be able to retrieve all of captures.

Comment: +1 for a correct regex, if not the [best solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11337444/20938).  Asd retrieving the group captures is not a problem.  That only applies when the group itself is under the control of a quantifier, like `(?:(\d+),?)+`. [read this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)